# Updating a chat channel without update message?

Tags: getstream-io

We update channels server-side using JS.

How can we update a channel without posting a message in the chat?

https://getstream.io/chat/docs/channel_update/?language=js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signature is like as following:

`channel.update(new_channel_data_object_to_be_merged, optional_update_message)`

Since message is optional, you can skip it and by only providing data, you can update a channel.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping but it doesn't seem to be the case. When I omit the update message, I get the following error:

Expected 2 arguments, but got 1: 
An argument for 'updateMessage' was not provided.

Comment: Is this a typescript error ? If so, there is a PR to fix it, should be released soon. https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-js/pull/305

Comment: Yes, it is: a typescript firebase cloud function to be exactly.

Comment: releasing in a few mins

Comment: Okay. We're waiting.